# iOSでAdmobを最新にしたらエラー

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios8, admob

お世話になります

iOS8でadmobの6はサポートされてないよってログに出てくるので、７にしようと思ってます。
で、cocoapodsでインストールしてるのですが、
Header Search Pathにある、admobのパスには、admobのファイルはおらず
以下のエラーで困っております

```
'GADBannerView.h' file not found
```

ちなみに、現状はこちらです

```
{15-02-26 20:06}[ruby-2.1.0]server:~/Documents/NeoCafesagashi2015@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ shiratsu% open NeoCafesagashi2015.xcworkspace
{15-02-26 20:08}[ruby-2.1.0]server:~/Documents/NeoCafesagashi2015@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ shiratsu% ls Pods/Headers/Public
FMDB          PonyDebugger  SMCalloutView SocketRocket
{15-02-26 20:10}[ruby-2.1.0]server:~/Documents/NeoCafesagashi2015@master✗✗✗✗✗✗ shiratsu% cat Podfile
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
pod 'SMCalloutView'
pod 'PonyDebugger'
pod 'FMDB'
```

ヘッダサーチパスは以下です

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK"
```

たしかにそんなとこには、ないので、直接、admobのファイルがある場所に向けたのですが、
今度は、Admobが二重で定義されてると怒られ、もう何が何だかわからず。。。

```
import "GADBannerView.h"

static const CGFloat CalloutYOffset = 10.0f;
static NSString * const urlKey = @"url";

@interface ViewController ()<GMSMapViewDelegate>
{
    BOOL _pinclflag;
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらくframeworkへ変更されたことが原因ではないでしょうか？
”Release Notes”にあるように7.0.0から”Released SDK as a framework.”へ変更されています。それに伴いCocoapodsで追加されるファイルもframeworkへ変更されています。

```
//#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerView>
```

Comment: おお、そういうことですか。。。すみません、気付いてませんでした。
ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: うまくいきました！ありがとうございます

Answer (score -1):

xcodeで`.h`ファイルを追加する必要があります。
GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerView.h

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Japanese! Would you please rewrite your answer in Japanese, if possible? 日本語での回答をおねがいできますか?